# Accessing elements in a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have elements in a nested list called "train_data" like in the example:

```
[0] [0.935897, 1.0, 1.0, 0.928772, 0.053629, 0.0, 39.559883, 0.009494, 0]
[1] [0.467681, 1.0, 1.0, 0.778987, 0.069336, 0.0, 56.571999, 0.024675, 0]
[2] [0.393258, 1.0, 1.0, 0.843201, 0.068779, 0.0, 66.866669, 0.069206, 1]
```

I would like to access all rows with the first 8 columns (all but the last one), and all rows with only the last column. I need to this without for loops, in a single line of code.

I tried something like this:

```
print train_data[0][:]
print train_data[:][0]
```

but this gives me the same result:

```
[0.935897, 1.0, 1.0, 0.928772, 0.053629, 0.0, 39.559883, 0.009494, 0]
[0.935897, 1.0, 1.0, 0.928772, 0.053629, 0.0, 39.559883, 0.009494, 0]
```

Could someone help me please?

Edit:

Sorry, the expected output for the first query is:

```
[0.935897, 1.0, 1.0, 0.928772, 0.053629, 0.0, 39.559883, 0.009494]
[0.467681, 1.0, 1.0, 0.778987, 0.069336, 0.0, 56.571999, 0.024675]
[0.393258, 1.0, 1.0, 0.843201, 0.068779, 0.0, 66.866669, 0.069206]
```

and for the second query is:

```
[0]
[0]
[1]
```

Comment: what's d expected output

Comment: You should use a `numpy` array, which offers slicing on multiple dimensions, rather than nested lists. Alternatively, `[row[:-1] for row in train_data]` will get you what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are expecting this

```
L1 = [x[0:-1] for x in train_data]
L2 = [x[-1] for x in train_data]

for x in L1:
    print x

for x in L2:
    print [x]
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `[:-1]` slicing for get all elements except the last one !

```
>>> l1=[0.935897, 1.0, 1.0, 0.928772, 0.053629, 0.0, 39.559883, 0.009494, 0]
>>> l2=[0.467681, 1.0, 1.0, 0.778987, 0.069336, 0.0, 56.571999, 0.024675, 0]
>>> l3=[0.393258, 1.0, 1.0, 0.843201, 0.068779, 0.0, 66.866669, 0.069206, 1]
>>> l=[l1,l2,l3]
>>> [i[:-1] for i in l]
[[0.935897, 1.0, 1.0, 0.928772, 0.053629, 0.0, 39.559883, 0.009494], [0.467681, 1.0, 1.0, 0.778987, 0.069336, 0.0, 56.571999, 0.024675], [0.393258, 1.0, 1.0, 0.843201, 0.068779, 0.0, 66.866669, 0.069206]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there really a good reason to do this in a oneliner? I mean why is that a requirement?

```
print [i[:-1] for i in l]  # All rows with all cols - 1
print [i[-1] for i in l]  # All rows with last col
```

But even if the loop is not explicit with a for, it's implicit as a comprehensive list...

edit: 1 → -1 for second line of code, my mistake

Comment: `i[1]` is the second column, not the last one => `i[-1]`