# Indexing certain elements in a nested list, for all nests

Tags: r, list, indexing, nested-lists, lapply

I have a list which contains more lists of lists:

```
results <- sapply(c(paste0("cv_", seq(1:50)), "errors"), function(x) NULL)

## Locations for results to be stored
step_results <- sapply(c("myFit", "forecast", "errors"), function(x) NULL)
step_errors <- sapply(c("MAE", "MSE", "sign_accuracy"), function(x) NULL)
final_error <- sapply(c("MAE", "MSE", "sign_accuracy"), function(x) NULL)

for(i in 1:50){results[[i]] <- step_results}
for(i in 1:50){results[[i]][[3]] <- step_errors}
results$errors <- final_error
```

Now in this whole structure, I would like to sum up all the values in `sign_accuracy` and save them in `results$errors$sign_accuracy`

I could maybe do this with a for-loop, indexing with i:

```
## This is just an example - it won't actually work!
sign_acc <- matrix(nrow = 50, ncol = 2)
for (i in 1:50){
     sign_acc[i, ] <- `results[[i]][[3]][[3]]`
     results$errors$sign_accuracy <- sign_acc
}
```

If I remember correctly, in Matlab there is something like `list(:)`, which means all elements. [In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27521956/accessing-elements-in-a-nested-list) I have seen something like `list(0:-1)`, which also means all elements.

**What is the elegent R equivalent?** I don't really like loops.

I have seen [methods using the *apply*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016359/how-to-directly-select-the-same-column-from-all-nested-lists-within-a-list) family of functions. With something like `apply(data, "[[", 2)`, but can't get it to work for deeper lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can do what you want with

```
results$errors$sign_accuracy <- do.call(sum, lapply(results, function(x){x[[3]][[3]]}))
```

`lapply` loops through the first layer of `results`, and pulls out the third element of the third element for each. `do.call(sum` catches all the results and sums them.

The real problems with lists arise when the nesting is more irregular, or when you need to loop through more than one index. It can always be done in the same way, but it gets extraordinarily ugly very quickly.

Comment: This was the solution I actually ended up using, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Did you try with `c(..., recursive)`?

Here is an option with a short example at the end:

```
sumList <- function(l, label) {
    lc <- c(l, recursive=T)
    filter <- grepl(paste0("\\.",label, "$"), names(lc)) | (names(lc) == label)
    nums <- lc[filter]
    return(sum(as.numeric(nums)))
}

ex <- list(a=56,b=list("5",a=34,list(c="3",a="5")))
sumList(ex,"a")
```

Comment: So long as no terrible person names a list item `"a.b.c"` or something like that...